# Is "We can't guarantee your safety" always a threat?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiom-meaning

I can only think of scenarios when I have heard the phrase, "we can't guarantee your safety," uttered in a way that seems like a threat.  This seems *likely* because of the odd phrasing: Nobody can *guarantee* anyone's safety.  So (I reason) making the statement is not a tautology but is rather stating that the party issuing the threat is in a position to increase the peril to the subject if not placated.

Examples:

- *If you don't bribe my guards, I can't guarantee your safety crossing this frontier.*  (My translation: We'll rob or kill you down the road if you don't pay us protection money.)
- *If you don't pay protection money, I can't guarantee the safety of your business.*  (My translation: Pay us protection money or goons will trash your business.)

Is it in fact *always* reasonably and properly interpreted as a threat?  Sort of like, "Nice business you have here.  Would be a shame if anything were to happen to it!"

How about: "If you don't leave this question open, I can't guarantee the safety of this site?"

Comment: It may be stated as a neutral statement.  Eg, you talk to a park ranger about climbing some mountain, he may say you're allowed to do it, but he can't guarantee your safety.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about the English language- i.e. this discussion could be had in French just as easily.

Comment: @Jim - This is about the usage of a phrase.  I can't find [anything in the scope](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that says that a question is off-topic just because it could be asked of another language.  (Nor do I know French, or know whether this phrase and its connotation translate perfectly to that language, which sounds like a separate and off-topic question.)

Comment: The phrase often arises in the context of putting individuals on notice that if they proceed with some activity, or venture, they do so at their own risk. The crucial point of such notification is that it constitutes a disclaimer (or an attempt at a disclaimer) of legal responsibility for the safety of the individuals thus notified. There is no implication in that case that the person giving the warning is contemplating doing anything to injure or endanger the notified individuals.

Comment: There is something in the wording of the question that gives the impression that you(fetwet) are making an argument to this forum, not looking for thoughts of how the term is used in other ways without a threat intended.  The use of 'disclaimers' has gone somewhat out of fashion but that has more to do with  the evolution of tort law I believe...but that is an entirely other discussion.

Comment: It is true that people saying "I can't guarantee your safety" are almost certainly not guaranteeing safety in other instances either.  Why not just say . .. "We will also drive mountain bikers up to the slide array but 'be warned, there are dangerous conditions there"?  They could of course and that's a more modern way of saying it I suppose.  The "I can't guarantee" is just an old fashioned turn of speech that suggests they normally would have your best interests in mind (even if not guaranteeing them)

Answer (score 2):

**No, sometimes the statement has its simple straightforward meaning,** which is not a threat.

A cliched and usually fictional example is the leader who insists on talking to his people in the open. The head of security might say, "I can't guarantee your safety", and just means what he says.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this, because it's not possible for the head of security to *ever literally guarantee* the safety of the principal.  So is this just a colloquialism, like, "I *guarantee* you'll have a good time!"

Comment: @feetwet A guarantee is a promise or an assurance. Everyone recognizes that promises are sometimes broken and assurances are sometimes empty.